# How to create a Cocoa Touch Framework with Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift-package-manager

I am using Swift Package Manager to create a Framework from console with the followings commands:

swift package init --type=library

swift package generate-xcodeproj

The output Framework created using this commands is a **Cocoa Framework**.

How could I create a **Cocoa Touch Framework** instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cocoa Touch Framework** - is an iOS framework, SwiftPM currently doesn't support iOS.

Here is a quote from *Swift Package Manager* [Readme](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/55acae81c69c992b9517faee0f8464e3b63b8677/Sources/Commands/SwiftPackageTool.swift#L267)

> Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms.

But it will be supported in the future. You can read more about it here - [Swift Package Manager 3.0 Project Status](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160815/026456.html)

If you want to make iOS framework you can run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and change the framework target to iOS. You can also pass custom `.xcconfig` file with a custom configurations
`swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Configs.xcconfig`

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.